# for loop with sublists in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to do calculations and append variables to sublists in python using this loop:

```
for latLong in latLongList[:-1]:
    distance = findDistance(latLong[0], latLong[1], usrLocation[0], usrLocation[1])
    latLong.append(distance)
```

It is working perfectly except, it doesn't perform the operations on the last sub list and I am confused on why this is.  I know I have to modify my loop definition to include that last element but I am unsure how.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're specifically removing last element with `latLongList[:-1]`. Just use `latLongList`.

Comment: Are you trying to reverse latLongList? That's `latLongList[::-1]` you're removing the last entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not require a slice of the list, simply iterate through the entire list. Ah, while writing this it seems @Daniel has answered the question quite well. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the last element included, loop till the last element:

```
for latLong in latLongList:
    distance = findDistance(latLong[0], latLong[1], usrLocation[0], usrLocation[1])
    latLong.append(distance)
```